# flash.message in grails filter

Tags: grails, grails-filters

in my Grails application , i made a filter on a controller , all working fine except this part :

```
flash.message = message(code: 'empSeeker.profileExists')
```

and the error is :

```
Message:No signature of method: com.MyApp.filters.HRCheckFilters.message() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[code:empSeeker.profileExists]] Possible solutions: isCase(java.lang.Object)
```

but if i changed it with `flash.message="Any message"` it works,

Any reason why it is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that most things like this that work in a controller also work in filters, but apparently not. In this case there's a workaround that's actually a better approach.

`message` works in a controller because controllers support calling taglibs directly, and if the namespace is `g` then you can omit it, so calling `message` or `g.message` in a controller both invoke the `<g:message>` taglib. But all the taglib does is render messages from the `messageSource` Spring bean, so you can skip a layer or two of indirection and call that directly.

Add this import to your filters class

```
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder
```

and this dependency injection

```
def messageSource
```

and then you can set the flash message with

```
flash.message = messageSource.getMessage('empSeeker.profileExists',
                                          null, LocaleContextHolder.locale)
```